# How to get existing item's collection which is in ms sql db, using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I've just started to explore Entity Framework, and its realy great! But now I have question. In my db "Products" I have table's Product, Component, Product_Component (it's many-to-many connection). I created an .edmx file in my c# project and choose this 3 tables. Now, i can see  in listbox items of tables, for example, i can see all rows of Products table using

```
ProductsEntities db = new ProductsEntities();
LstBox.ItemsSource = db.Product;
```

but all the `Product` has collection of `Components`, and I want to bind for example collection `Components` which are in my `Product` on index 2. (Product "cake" in table `Product` has `Component`s  "suqar", "salt", "flour"). How can I make this thing? I tried to get `Product` by index, but it doesn't works. Maybe it's a stupid question, sorry, but please, help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why you couldn't make direct relation from Product --> Component 1xProduct-->Many Components. Why you need `Product_Component`. If you will do like I said you can easly get what you want like that:

```
db.Products.First(e=>e.Id==2).Components.ToList();
```

will get a list of components of product with id = 2;

Edited:

Use like that

```
List<Component> components = new List<Component>();
db.Products.First(e=>e.Id==2).Product_Components.ToList().ForEach(e=>components.Add(e.Component));
```

Adding new component to product:

```
Product someProduct = db.Product.First(e=>e.Name=="coolProduct")
Component component = db.Component.First(e=>e.Name=="Fish");
someProduct.Product_Component.Add(new Product_Component(){Component=component...});
db.SaveChanges();
```

New way to add new component to product:

```
Product someProduct = db.Product.First(e=>e.Name=="coolProduct")
Component component = db.Component.First(e=>e.Name=="Fish");
Component_Product component_product = new Component_Product(){Component = component, Product = product};
db.SaveChanges();
```

New-New solution:

```
Product someProduct = db.Product.First(e=>e.Name=="coolProduct")
Component component = db.Component.First(e=>e.Name=="Fish");
Component_Product component_product = new Component_Product(){Component = component, Product = product};
db.Component_Product.Add(component_product);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I have Product_Component table because yesterday I tried use ADO.NET, and today I saw Entity Framework.

Comment: Actually you have a right structure of BD, at the begining I was mistaken. See what I added after `Edited:`

Comment: And now it doesnt works( Says that `db.Product.First(e1 => e1.id == 2).Product_Component.` doesnt has definition for `ForEach`(

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be:
db.Products.First(e=>e.Id==2).Product_Components.ToList().ForEach(e=>components.Add(e.Component));

Comment: Thanks, works! And if I want to add a component to product, I have to use something like `db.Product.First(e1 => e1.id == 4).Product_Component.Add(` but then it wants `Product_Component` not `Component` (it's logical). How can I add a `Component`?

Comment: Product someProduct = db.Product.First(e=>e.Name=="coolProduct")
Component component = db.Component.First(e=>e.Name=="Fish");
someProduct.Product_Component.Add(new Product_Component(){Component=component...});

Comment: and when I want to add this product to db - it says that there is an existing item with same name. I tried to delete it and than add modificated item, but there is an error says that I cant delete Product because it has relations, and the foreign key can not be null

Comment: You dont need to Add existing product once more, you just need to run db.SaveChanges(); and the data will fly to your db. Look at the example I have added to the end of my answer.

Comment: Just now tried `db.Product.First(e1 => e1.id == 4).Product_Component.Add(new Product_Component() { Component = db.Component.First(e1 => e1.id == 1) });` but whet I `db.SaveChanges();` there is `UpdateException, An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.`

Comment: Can you add the innerException to your question?

Comment: I dont have a `Update` method on my `db.Product`

Comment: It's my bad, you should try to find Update method. you just change the entity and then use db.SaveChanges();

Comment: Just Add this code and it will add Component.Name=="Fish" to Product.Name=="coolProduct":

   Product someProduct = db.Product.First(e=>e.Name=="coolProduct")
Component component = db.Component.First(e=>e.Name=="Fish");
someProduct.Product_Component.Add(new Product_Component(){Component=component...});
db.SaveChanges();

Comment: Nope, same innerException(

Comment: Can you write the body of the exception?

Comment: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table Product_Component when 'IDENETITY_INSERT' is set to OFF.

Comment: something in DB, but I can see this property in table  Product_Component

Comment: Ok try new solution I added after: "New way to add new component to product:" in my answer.

Comment: Try the "New-New solution:"

Comment: Yep, I added SET IDENTITY_INSERT Product_Component ON to my DB, and then use a new .edmx file, and then it start work. Thank you so much! You are really good man, I thank you for your time and help!)